# Why Mean Predictor has high bias for Regression Problem?

Tags: regression, parameter-estimation

This might be a simple question, but I am quite confused.

Q) If an unbiased estimator for a population is a sample mean then why if I predict sample mean as the estimator in a regression problem I get high bias?